# Calculation of overall effect size in meta analyses using random and fixed effect model

Tags: statistical-significance, meta-analysis, clinical-trials

As a pharmacist and non-statistician, I'm struggling to understand the interpretation of a [2019 meta-analysis on the effect of prazosin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1087079219302163).

I'm particularly interested in the the analysis of the 7 randomised controlled drug studies where it is argued that despite the by far largest (and most recent) individual study, including 58% of all investigated patients, showing a negative result for three respective outcomes (nightmare frequency, sleep quality, PTSD symptoms), overall the effect of prazosin on these outcomes would be statistically significant; and this also in spite of at least three of the seven studies showing non-significant outcomes for each of the three outcomes (see p-Values in figures 2-4).

The authors argue that, using a random effect model, the relative weight attributed to the largest study is only 19.1, however that even with the relative weight of 68.5 in the fixed effect model, the meta-analysis would show significant effects of prazosin.

This is far from intuitive to me and I would like to understand how to re-calculate these numbers. I've tried reading a couple of papers explaining the Q-test, I2, and the Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviews of Interventions so far.

I would be grateful for an hints understandable by non-statisticians, how to calculate the weights of individual study outcomes for random and fixed effect models and how to calculate overall effect sizes. I'm not averse to R, so please send the names of any helpful R packages, if you know any.